# What is the best pattern for working with regex results?

Tags: regex, rust, ownership

I am a Javascript dev looking to up my game with Rust.  I've read *The Rust Programming Language*, completed the tutorials, and successfully added Rust to a node project using FFI.  I would like to speed up a parser I wrote but think I'm missing a fundamental ownership concept.

The current challenge is simple: evaluate a regex for a named capture and change the value of the variable to the new captured value.

I've tried this fifteen ways using `unwrap` or nesting `Result`s and `Option`s.  It always comes down to a 'does not live long enough' error.

My most recent code looks like this:

```
let flag_re = compile_re(r"(?:\s*)([~])(?:\s*)(?P<FLAG>.)"); 

let mut flag : &str = "V";

for line in file.lines() {

    let mut current_line : String = line.unwrap();

    if flag_re.is_match(&current_line) {

        let new_flag = &flag_re.captures(&current_line).unwrap().name("FLAG").unwrap().clone();

        println!("old flag: {} new flag: {}",flag,new_flag);

        flag = new_flag;

    }
```

This works great if I comment out the `flag = new_flag` line.  But once I try to assign a value to `flag` I get a 'does not live long enough' ON THE `current_line` variable.  I get that `current_line` is short lived so I've tried `clone` and `to_owned` with no luck and leading me to be certain I've got some misunderstanding of the concepts.

I've tried to recreate this in the Rust playground with this code:

```
fn main() {
   let mut a: &str;
   {
     let b: &str = "B";
     a = b;  
   }
   println!("a: {} ",a);
}
```

But (wouldn't you know) this works?  So please be gentle on this Javascript guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `new_flag` is borrowed from `line`.  That is, `new_flag` can *only* exist so long as `line` continues to exist.  Once you fall out of the loop, `line` will be destroyed.

The simplest way to handle this is to switch from a borrowed string (`&str`) to an *owned* string (`String`).  That is, you want a value that owns its contents so that there is no borrowing in play.  The appropriate changes would be:

```rust
let mut flag = String::from("V"); // One way of constructing a String from a &str
...
    flag = new_flag.into(); // Another way, using inference
```

A *slightly* more efficient alternative would be to use `std::borrow::Cow`, but that's probably unnecessary in this context.

Comment: Thanks.  Changing to String works.   I did have to use:
` 'flag = new_flag.**to_string()**.into();'`  I assume this is due to the product of new_flag is a &str.

Comment: Correction: .to_string() is unnecessary.  Notice the errant & in the new_flag assignment.  Sorry for the confusion and thanks again for the help.